# Display Server console output on client browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, newman

I am developing a nodejs express application that-

- allows users to select the postman collection and environment on an html form
- runs the collection using nemwan's nodejs package.
- Returns the execution report as a file stream

**Problem Statement** - Some of our collections take a lot of time which leaves the users hanging. I want the users to be able to see the console output (newman logs) on their browser in real-time so that they can track the collection progress.

**newman.ejs (button that triggers ajax call) -**

```
<button type="button" id="run" class="btn">
    <i class="loading-icon fa fa-spinner fa-spin hide"></i>
    <span class="btn-txt">Click to Run</span>
</button>
```

**script.js (ajax call) -**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#run").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Ajax call initiated to run collection")
    $(".loading-icon").removeClass("hide");
    $(".btn").attr("disabled", true);
    $(".btn-txt").text("Running..");
    data = $('#collectionForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url: "/run",
        success: function(data)
        {   
            var blob = new Blob([data]);
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "report.html";
            link.click();
            $(".loading-icon").addClass("hide");
            $(".btn").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#run").text("Click to run");
        }
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Couldn’t you use SocketIO to send updates to the client?

Comment: @alecwilson I looked into both websocket and socket.io. I believe that would help if I wanted to send logs from server to client using console.log statements in my app. But what I want to display on the browser is the console output  generated by newman package itself --> nemwan.run(...) which is the package's method.

Comment: @alecwilson I achieved it by listening to various events thrown by newman package and socketIO.